# pyspark - read a file to RDD with N lines into one map

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a .txt file which has a multi-line data like this:

```
[t_1,
 t_2,
 t_3,
 t_4,
 ...]
```

I want to read it into a RDD via Pyspark API, the desired RDD like this:

```
[t_1,...,t_n,
 t_(n+1),...,t_(2n),
 t_(2n+1),...,t_(3n),
 ...]
```

Can someone give me an idea of it?

Thanks in advance